# Show Limited Data Using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

How can i put a limit on appended Data? Something Like Pagination.

E.g If I have **appended 5 comments**, Its should show me **3 latest comments**, other 2 comments should be **hidden** and should appear when click on **Show More Comments**. All i want to do with Jquery.

**Check Out Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/1/

Please take a look at this Image. Just to Clarify my Point:

[image]

**I am Providing my Code here too:**

**HTML:**

```
      <p>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_more">Add More</a>
      </p>

<table border="0" width="500" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody class="append_data"></tbody>

<tr>
  <td> 
      <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  </td> 
</tr> 

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#description{
    width:400px;    
}

.description_text{
    border:#333333 solid 1px;
    width:400px !important;
}

.append_data{
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        $(".append_data").append('<div class="description_text">'+description+'</div><br><br>');
                     });
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work. What are you asking for?

Comment: I have already explained it. I want to hide old comments. Just want to show 3 latest comments. Old comments should appear on clicking show more comments. And why down voted? All i want to do with Jquery

Comment: I don't know why someone else downvoted you.

Comment: These people should really give some reason for down voting :( So that we work on what we are doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var comments = $('.description_text').size();
if (comments > 3) {
    $('.description_text').slice(0,comments-3).hide();
}
```

But you will need to update the code to remove the BRs and add in some css padding, floating or similar.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jE9p/3/

Comment: Can you update my Fiddle ? And why down rated? I guess my question is valid.

Comment: I uprated your question.

Comment: fiddled now, extra details in answer

Comment: So can i view Old comments?